# SubSonic 2.x Substring of a column

Tags: subsonic

How do I write a SubSonic query similar to this is C#.net:

SELECT * FROM Users WHERE substr(last_name,1,1) = 'S';

I don't want to use "LIKE" it eats up performance.

Answer (score 2):

Don't think you can do this, you can use subsonic to execute the query itself though.

How to here:
http://subsonicproject.com/docs/CodingHorror